# Multiple scrollbars when there is a pop-up or modal window. What is the reason for implementing this design pattern?

Tags: popup, modal-dialog, scrollbar

I have noticed on certain websites that are implemented as a single page and free scrolling view in browsers that when you trigger a pop-up or modal window a second scrollbar appears to allow the user to scroll through the content of the window. The primary scrollbar is also active but not very effective since the pop-up or modal window blocks out most of the screen.

I cannot imagine that this implementation approach would have very strong usability reasons, so I was wondering if there is a valid technical reason or constraint. But if there is a valid argument from a UX design perspective then I am also interested in finding out the rationale behind it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When content overflows (too big to fit in the container element), the browser adds a scrollbar. Looks like in your case, the modal is taking up 100% width/height of the viewport, but it's still too small to fit all the content, hence the vertical scrollbar.

To get rid of the scrollbar, people usually add `overflow: hidden` on the element which hides the scrollbars, but also doesn't allow the user to scroll. This is fine if the content is not important... such as a graphic that's meant to be a background image or something of that sort.

It's poor design in my opinion. If there is enough content that the user will have to scroll to see it, there's no reason to put it in a modal. If you have a modal, keep it small. In some cases where it's necessary though, you can hide the main scroll-bar when the modal is in view.

Comment: Is it also not common practice to disable the outer scrollbar if they end up showing both scrollbars? In this example you can interact with both scrollbars, which makes things even more confusing in my opinion.

Comment: Yep, you can just add an overflow: hidden on the body to hide the outer scrollbar while the modal is open and remove it when closed. Some developers are just lazy or inexperienced or might just not know that their modal is causing scrollbars (for example if they don't test their site with multiple browser dimensions)